# WCF in StreamInSight

Tags: wcf, streaminsight

How to implement the StreamInsight server, Input Adapter and Output Adapter as WCF Service?
Please provide me some sample projects..

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [StreamInsight product team samples on CodePlex](http://streaminsight.codeplex.com/releases/view/46435)? They include a basic version of WCF input/output adapters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to send StreamInsight events out through a web endpoint (SOAP or REST), you can also use the StreamInsight adapter that I built (http://seroter.wordpress.com/2010/07/09/sending-streaminsight-events-to-biztalk-through-new-web-soaprest-adapter/).  The StreamInsight product team samples have a good example for receiving WCF input.